# Recover classifier from Jupyter and Anaconda

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

So I installed Anaconda and have had an environment set up for machine learning.

I launch the environment in Jupyter Notebook.

In my notebook I declare a new "classifier" object and train my model, it took a few days, after that I lost power and when I rebooted and turned Jupiter back on and tried testing my classifier it says classifier not detected.

By any chance has the classifier been saved somewhere as a file and I can import that file and keep working with that model or did I lose my classifier object and have to retrain my model?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add( Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu') )
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(activation='relu', units=128))
classifier.add(Dense(activation='sigmoid', units=1))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,shear_range=0.2,zoom_range=0.2,horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('Convolutional_Neural_Networks/lol/training_set', target_size=(64,64), batch_size=32, class_mode='binary')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('Convolutional_Neural_Networks/lol/test_set', target_size=(64,64), batch_size=32, class_mode='binary')
from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

#This is the step taht took like 3 days
classifier.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch=8000, epochs=10, validation_data=test_set, validation_steps=800)
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('Convolutional_Neural_Networks/lol_tests/test1.jpg', target_size=(64,64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)

#ERROR:NameError: name 'classifier' is not defined
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] <= 0.5:
    prediction = 'dog'
else:
    prediction = 'cat'
print(prediction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that you have shown you haven't saved your model, meaning that you have lost it. Guess you need to retrain it! 
This time though remember to save it:

```
classifier.save('classifier.h5')
```

So you will be able to load it next time.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!